# Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I updated `compileSDkversion` from 27 to 28.

Added in `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in `build gradle` added:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.2'
```

Refactored support libraries to androidX libraries in build.gradle.

I'm getting a build error:

> Could not find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0

What is the problem? What else should I change?

P.S: this is expoKit react-native project

Comment: `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0` is not a valid dependency .. Are you having this dependency in your gradle anywhere ?

Comment: @ADM I don't have it in gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have found a solution.

I used in `Android Studio: Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX`.

It solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was regarding some of the dependencies, which were using `supportLibVersion` property to resolve the `android.support` dependency.

**Short:**

Check your project's `build.gradle` and see if your `supportLibVersion` has as value `28.0.0` and set it to the value you need, which seems to be `1.0.2`.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion =
        minSdkVersion =
        compileSdkVersion =
        targetSdkVersion =
        supportLibVersion = "1.0.2" <---- here
    }
```

**Long:**

For example, one of my dependencies stated this dependency:

```
"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${safeExtGet('supportLibVersion', '28.0.0')}"
```

My `supportLibVersion` property was still set to `28.0.0` for the old support version.

My guess is that Jetifier, which is used to translate the dependencies to AndroidX, replaces the `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'` part with well, but if the dependecy states the version of the library with the `supportLibVersion` property, the resolution of the translation will use that value, so it will end up trying to find `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:28.0.0` which doesn't exist.

I found really helpful the [AndroidX migration table](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) to understand how Jetifier translates.

Hope it helps!